# Can a scalar field also has positive or zero pressure?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, cosmology, pressure, cosmological-inflation

In inflation theory, the inflaton field produce negative pressure to drive inflation.

But now I’m going to ask about scalar fields in general, not the inflaton field.

Can a scalar field also has positive or zero pressure, like radiation or matter?

Comment: Yes, a scalar field with a negative potential has positive pressure.

Comment: As do the particles associated with the field.

Comment: All quantum fields have associated particles: the electron field has electrons, photon field has photons, etc.  Same is true of scalar fields.  When inflation ends, the inflaton oscillates about its minimum leading to a condensate of inflaton particles.  These particles gravitate just like ordinary matter (or radiation, depending on their energy).

Comment: @knzhou What is negative potential? I’ve never heard of it before.

Comment: @parker The inflation field has a potential $V(\phi)$. The value of the potential can be a negative number.